# Pass WindowsPrincipal user to another web application shown in iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I dont know if its possible, but ....

On first site the user is authenticated using active directory and got WindowsPrincipal user.

Then in iframe will shown a second site. How to pass an object User or credentials of authentication to second site?

How to authenticate the user with the same credentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for **SSO** (single sing on).

It depends on how you make your authentication in application, so it's hard to advice you.

But if you want to understand problem you could start from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic).